# Path of the ios application on device

Tags: iphone, filepath

Well, I would just like to know is it possible to know the path of the app? I used the following code

```
[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath];
```

It retrieved the below value. That is correct.

```
/var/mobile/Applications/FBE187F1-256D-495D-852B-53AECD4F4C23/Test_Data_Fetch.app
```

And I would like to know, is it possible to check the existence of other app? The problem is `FBE187F1-256D-495D-852B-53AECD4F4C23` this particular directory value changes for every app. I would really like to know if it is possible!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally, using the **Mac program iExplorer** we can look at any App’s data. This is not related to my question, though it is quiet useful!! Was able to achieve my goal!! :]*

Answer (score 1):

Your application cannot access anything outside sandbox so you can't search file system directly for a given application.

One possible solution is if application you are interested in handles custom url scheme, then  you can check if that url scheme can be opened:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:customScheme];
BOOL appProbablyExists = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
```

**Update:** [This article](http://danielamitay.com/blog/2012/8/6/how-to-detect-installed-ios-apps) describes several possible approaches, but it seems there's no definite way to get list of installed applications using public API

Comment: Actually, I found somewhere on net it is possible to list all the applications installed on the device. So just wanted to know it is really possible!!

Comment: Do you have a link for that Nina?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-can-an-iOS-app-get-the-list-of-all-the-other-apps-installed-on-the-device

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html I dont know how much  possible it is :(